# amp for a viewing room

Tags: amplifier, playback, film, edit

Hi guys I'm starting work at a film production company and they asked me to source an amp for playback in the edit  suite for playback of the project to the director, producers and investors. Which brands should I be looking at?

Comment: an amp to handle 5.1, right?

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be an amp?  If you're looking for a 5.1 amp, you've really only got Denon that's professional before you have to muck through the home theater market.

The best solution is running a 5.1 sound card or interface that will output to a mixing console that will feed powered studio monitors.  A lot more control and options.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [Denon](http://www.denon.com/Pages/home.aspx).